# How can i cut letters from extracted value in imacros?

Tags: imacros, shift

Can anyone please say me how shift() works in imacros?
Iam n newbee and now very little of javascript. Also iam from Germany, so sorry for my bad  english :)

I extract a code. Than i want to delete the first 2 letters, and work with the rest.
Example:
Extracted = AB12345678
I only need 12345678

I tried this. Extract the text works, but there is an error in the EVAL / shift{} statement.

> TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:grid-2
>
> TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=name:aid* EXTRACT=TXT
>
> SET EAN EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.shift();")

I tried this bevore:

> SET EAN EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.slice(\"'\", 2);")

Than i get only the first 2 letters ( AB ).
When i set -2 the last 2 where cut of and i get AB123456.

So i think shift is the right for me, but i stuck here :(

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use this method so I go for JS.

when you use iimGetLastExtract() you can store it to text variable and...

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";

macro +="TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:grid-2"+"\n";

macro +="TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=name:aid* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";

iimPlay(macro)

text=iimGetLastExtract();

text=text.slice(,-2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when i play this code, i get an error msg: SyntaxError: syntax error, line NaN (Error code: -991)

Comment: The problem is fixed.

Comment: I have played with your code, and already seen the s in iimPlay ;). But that was not the Problem. The Problem is that i know not much about js. so i have to trie to build it in the iim code. that is my code now:  var macro
var maxlines=51
for (var i = 1; i < maxlines; i++)
{
macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:grid-2<SP>alpha"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=name:aid* EXTRACT=TXT"+"\n";
macro +="SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\Dokumente<SP>und<SP>Einstellungen\\... FILE=123.csv"+"\n";
iimPlay(macro)
text=iimGetLastExtract();
text=text.slice(,-2);
}

Comment: it works only until iimPlay(macro), when i delete the two text=... elements. the whole code gives me an error on line text=text.slice(;-2); also the loop funktion doesnt work. it only extracted the first position

Comment: now i have found the error. in your code there is missing the beginning `text=text.slice(2,-2);` this code only cuts the first two letters from the value, but now i get no more error msg. because of this, i was abel to fix my code. `SET EAN EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.slice(\"2\",20);")` now it works as it should do. the first two letters where cut